# When defining a typescript can I partially define a key?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I know I can do:

```
interface Library {
  [propName: string]: string;
}
```

to compensate for an unknown key name. However, I know I'll have multiple keys that are generated but the structure is important and known. Such as:

```
interface Library {
  Books.[bookId].token: string;
  Books.[bookId].accessKey: string;
}
```

In the above case I have an API I don't control with a response that I need to write an interface for that accounts for both of those. I could just `[propName: string]: string;` for them to account for it but I'd like to keep the structure if I can. Is that possible?

Comment: You can't use dotted paths in interfaces, but yo can do it the "normal" way with nested object types, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NdavMm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I agree, it's weird. I'm literally looking an API response that has that dot like structure as a key/value pair. I assumed it wasn't possible but thought maybe I didn't know something they did.

Comment: Oh, uh, well you *can* use dots in key names, but they aren't paths.  If you are actually getting keys with dots in them, maybe you're looking for [something like this instead](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3QVm)?  If so I'll write up an answer for it.  Otherwise, uh, help

Comment: @jcalz Yes! Ugh, I just assumed you can't use a template literal in an interface like that so I didn't even try it. If you could put an answer like that in here I'll select it. thanks!

Comment: @dcp3450 you can also make generic `type Library<bookId>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the equivalent of a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) where the unknown keys are restricted to a pattern, this can be done with a [template string pattern index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) as long as that pattern can be represented by a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) with placeholders like `` `${string}` `` as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598).  For your example it would look like:

```
interface Library {
  [k: `Books.${string}.token`]: string;
  [k: `Books.${string}.accessKey`]: string;
}

let l: Library;
l = {
  "Books.abc.token": "a", // okay
  "Books.abc.accessKey": "b", // okay
  "Books.abc.oops": "c" // error
};
```

Note that this is still an index signature and as such it doesn't actually *require* any properties. Sometimes people think `{[k: K]: V}` means that the object contains all possible keys of type `K`, but it actually means that *if* a key is of type `K`, *then* the value will be of type `V`:

```
l = {}; // okay
```

And also note that the placeholders for `token` and for `accessKey` are unrelated to each other:

```
l = {
  "Books.def.token": "a",
  "Books.ghi.accessKey": "b"
} // okay
```

This might or might not matter for your use cases, but this is essentially the equivalent of a `string` index signature as asked in the question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAEZTlAnsgbwFgAoZZAbQGsAuZAAwCEB7ZqgZwDoASA9sKKADmAX05g2EEPQC6dfoJBCA3KXLU6TVhx58BwsYiTt2AaQi5Z8-UtUkRpUgBsIYZE7rosOXHefIAXkI1ZAAiFjYuOAwEcUkQULpQuFCAGhDw7SiYziMIE3NcRLCMNIyInWjY1gAHdmLQhFDkAHoW5GgoZihSET8SJ0DCPtb2tjhcRwGh4jIwiq4AEwgYOKopBpT0uczIziEAC2BchGMzCwbS3tHkccmSIA)